# Split string into multiple substrings starting and ending with special character

Tags: javascript, react-native, interactjs

I have a string like

`"i have #newCar and the #noTime in #Days"`

and I want to extract words starting with `#`:

`a = "#newCar","#noTime',"#Days"`

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex for this purpose

```
const s = "i have #newCar and the #noTime in #Days"
const regex = /#[a-zA-Z]+\b/g

console.log(s.match(regex)) // ["#newCar", "#noTime", "#Days"]
```

Comment: thank you...but how can convert the array ["#newCar", "#noTime", "#Days"] to "#newCar", "#noTime", "#Days"   like this ?

Comment: Do you want all of that in a single string?

Comment: not single string three different string separated with comma

Comment: That's exactly what console.log is printing here.